# Too frequent Random Byte Collision

Tags: c#, random, birthday-paradox

I've written a program to simulate collisions in accordance to the typical "Birthday Problem".

However, even taking that into account I'm seeing collisions happen far too frequently in the random data, to the point where my generator is reporting collisions in random 1024 byte data which should be infeasible if my code is correct.

I suspect my problem is in my implementation of my EqualityComparer

```cs
void Main()
{
    var gen = System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
    
    foreach (int i in new int[]{1,2,3,4,8,16,64,256,1024})
    {
        (var dupe, var counter) = BirthdayByte(gen, i);
        Console.WriteLine($"{i:00}. Found duplicate byte after {counter:000000} tries: {BitConverter.ToString(dupe)} ");    
    }
}

public (byte[], long) BirthdayByte(RandomNumberGenerator rng, int bufferLength)
{
    var found = false;
    HashSet<byte[]> members = new HashSet<byte[]>(new ByteArrayComparer());
    byte[] randomBytes = new byte[bufferLength];
    long counter = 0;
    while (!found)
    {
        counter++;
        rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);
        found = members.Contains(randomBytes);
        if (!found)
        {
            members.Add(randomBytes);
        }
    }
    return (randomBytes, counter);
}

public class ByteArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<byte[]>
{
    bool IEqualityComparer<byte[]>.Equals(byte[] x, byte[] y)
    {
        if(x.Length != y.Length) return false;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            if(!x[i].Equals(y[i])) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    int IEqualityComparer<byte[]>.GetHashCode(byte[] obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            int hash = 17;
            foreach (byte element in obj)
            {
                hash = hash * 31 + element.GetHashCode();
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

One typical output is:

```
01. Found duplicate byte after 000017 tries: D8 
02. Found duplicate byte after 000044 tries: 9D-59 
03. Found duplicate byte after 000536 tries: 49-DF-8D 
04. Found duplicate byte after 004234 tries: 09-02-ED-18 
08. Found duplicate byte after 095210 tries: 46-1D-86-37-00-ED-AD-6D 
16. Found duplicate byte after 040305 tries: 79-EF-C4-C8-49-97-DD-8A-28-45-CD-D8-E8-EA-58-3E 
64. Found duplicate byte after 068927 tries: 57-12-3E-6D-EF-A1-90-F0-F2-F9-3F-E8-C8-76-0E-15-E9-AF-F0-D4-14-C4-AA-85-D6-D0-56-D6-CB-66-1C-7D-F0-5B-73-CC-67-90-F7-73-0D-DB-7B-64-FC-D8-D3-86-6D-38-DD-6E-9F-1E-18-A3-C1-96-86-C2-5A-BD-47-76 
256. Found duplicate byte after 073932 tries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
1024. Found duplicate byte after 026518 tries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
```

The first result with a single byte feels about right, but I'd expect that doubling the buffer length ought to make the search take significantly longer and that doesn't seem to be the case.

I've tried printing out the bytes and while they appear to be "genuine" collisions I struggle to believe that I'm really generating random collisions so easily.

Is the problem in the way I'm filling the `randomBytes` buffer, or a problem in my `ByteArrayComparer`?

Comment: I wonder if it's the actual collision or your hashset/comparer double reports a false positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is inserting the same array again and again in the `members` collection. You should create a new array on each iteration:

```
while (!found)
{
    byte[] randomBytes = new byte[bufferLength];
    rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);
    found = !members.Add(randomBytes);
}
```

Comment: I'm confused why this appears to still work at all?

Is it that it'll essentially get a match as soon as GetHashCode happens to collide which is of course much more often?

Comment: @Eterm the `HashSet<T>` collection operates under the assumption that the items it contains have an immutable hash code. If the hash code of an item changes over time, the `HashSet<T>` won't be able to find this item because it will search for it in the wrong bucket. Here is an interesting reading: [Guidelines and rules for GetHashCode](https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/)

Comment: Thanks @theodor  That makes sense, so after a while it randomly finds a matching HashCode and then when it checks equality on it, it then matches because all the elements are actually identical because the same array was inserted.
 That also explains why it seems to behave correctly for 1 byte but deviates further as the number of bytes increases, because it's capped to the time to match a (single byte) hash code.

Comment: @Eterm I wouldn't even try to make sense of it. The behavior of the `HashSet<T>` class, when the hash code immutability requirement is violated, is simply undefined. :-)